# Kerberos JAAS with Service name

Tags: security, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, sasl

I'm trying to set up Zookeeper / Kafka Kerberos authentication but my keytab were created in an interesting way:

```
ktpass -princ zookeeper/hostname@TEST -mapuser zookeeper -mapOp add -Target TEST
```

so it turns out I can do this

```
kinit zookeeper@TEST
```

or this:

```
kinit zookeeper@TEST -S zookeeper/hostname@TEST
```

but I can't do this:

```
kinit zookeeper/hostname@TEST
kinit: Client 'zookeeper/hostname@TEST' not found in Kerberos Database while getting initial credentials
```

So this JAAS file will work:

```
Server {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="/path/to/server/keytab"
       storeKey=true
       useTicketCache=false
       principal="zookeeper@TEST";
};
```

but this one won't:

```
Server {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="/path/to/server/keytab"
       storeKey=true
       useTicketCache=false
       principal="zookeeper/hostname@TEST";
};
```

So how can I make this work using a JAAS file? I couldn't find an option to have multiple principals or to specify a service name like for `kinit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Active Directory, you need to map your User Principal Name zookeeper to a Service Principal Name

```
setspn -s zookeeper/localhost@TEST zookeeper
```

More details [here](https://serverfault.com/a/567562/113886)

And you still use zookeeper@TEST as principal in your JAAS file.

Comment: Thanks! Can you set spn to multiple host? The idea was to get one user and several principals

Comment: yes : `setspn -s zookeeper/host_1@TEST zookeeper` `setspn -s zookeeper/host_2@TEST zookeeper`